# Asignar Valores a una selección de un option value (html y js)

Tags: php, javascript, html, select

Buen día, necesito asignar a un **option value** un valor, el cual pueda usar para llenar un input al cual le debo concatenar un valor autoincremental para luego ser guardado en una base de datos ya que de este generaré códigos de archivos de un SIG.

**Tengo algo más o menos así:**

```
<label for="proceso">Proceso: </label>
<select id="" name="proceso" class="form-control">                                            
     <option value="-1" selected="" disabled="">Seleccione...</option>
     <option value="1">D1. GESTIÓN ESTRATÉGICA</option>
     <option value="2">V1. VENTAS</option>
     <option value="3">V2. ABASTECIMIENTO</option>
     <option value="4">V3. PRODUCCIÓN</option>
     <option value="5">V4. LOGISTICA</option>
     <option value="6">A1. GESTIÓN HUMANA</option>
     <option value="9">A2. GESTIÓN FINANCIERA</option>
     <option value="10">A3. GESTIÓN DE SISTEMAS INTEGRADOS</option>
     <option value="11">A4. GESTIÓN DE LA INFRAESTRUCTURA</option>
 </select>
```

[image: Esta imagen muestra lo que quiero hacer pero a nivel de proceso, ya que esta tiene es la parte de creación de documento dentro de un proceso]
**Lo que quiero es que en este input:**

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
   <label for="codigo">Código interno:</label>
   <input style="" type="text" maxlength="250" id="kodigo" name="codigo" readonly="" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="">
</div>
```

Me quede algo como:
Si selecciono D1. GESTIÓN ESTRATÉGICA, entonces en el input me cree una cadena: con D1, siguiendo el la siguiente regla: ***D1.PR##.NOMBREPROCESO*** y así sucesivamente **D1.PR01.REVISIÓN** ...; si selecciono V4, entonces debería quedar ***V4.PR##.NOMBREPROCESO ya luego entrar a validar para que no hayan procesos iguales.

Por este lado es para empezar, ya que luego según cada Proceso, puedo ingresar a cada uno y crear un archivo dentro del proceso. Y seguiría con un consecutivo similar, pero para empezar quisiera que me colaboraran con esto por ahora, ya luego consultaría por lo que sigue o con la solución de esta presente duda ya podría resolver la siguiente.

Les agradezco muchísimo. Disculpen lo extendido, es mi primer post y quería dejarlo un poco claro.  Así que también espero contribuir con muchos otros.

Comment: para guardar en el option el valor a concatenar puedes usar data-attributes asi "D1. GESTIÓN ESTRATÉGICA" puede almacenar D1 donde no me queda claro es el formato D1.PR##.NOMBREPROCESO el numero ## es autoincremental por opcion o para todas es decir si escojo D1 como primer valor seria  D1.PR01.NOMBREPROCESO pero si luego escojo V4 seria V4.PR02.NOMBREPROCESO y el nombre del proceso de donde lo saco o el usuario lo indica , espero puedas ser mas claro

Comment: @stanchacon gracias por tú aporte, la forma de implementar el data attributes es así?   **<option value="1" data-attributes="D1">D1. GESTIÓN ESTRATÉGICA</option>** y luego en el input cómo lo utilizo?  Y con respecto a la aclaración que me solictas el **##** es autoincremental  por opción, más no para todas, osea que cada valor de los select generan un nuevo autoincremental;  y el nombre del proceso el usuario lo indica. Muchas gracias!,

Comment: los data atributtes se utilizan asi **<option data-codigo="D1"></option>** para acceder al atributo de la opcion seleccionada lo harias asi **$( "#myselect option:selected" ).data("codigo")**, en cuanto al incremental no se si esto sera un problema ya que suponiendo que un usuario ingrese un proceso D101 un dia y al dia siguiente ingrese otro ahora seria D102, si es asi creo que eso debes manejarlo con la DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el siguiente código se toman ciertas consideraciones:

1. tomo en cuenta que tus códigos de proceso no pueden ser el valor de tus option por x o y razon por lo que utilizo **[data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/como/Usando_atributos_de_datos)** para ello.
2. En cuanto a la parte autoincremental no se si esta data se almacenara en DB y por ende cada vez que haga una inserción debería obtener la secuencia correspondiente al tipo de proceso, por lo que utilizo **[local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)** para obtener la sequencia desde un array predefinido ten en cuenta que esta información se pierde al limpiar la memoria del navegador.
3. Puesto que StackOverflow no admite local storage en su sandbox adjunto el siguiente [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a5m7hyqt/32/) para que corrobores el codigo.
4. si deseas implementar la db solo debes utilizar ajax y reemplazar esta linea `codigos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('infoProceso'))` por la llamada ajax y te ahorrarias de igual forma el tener que almacenar en local storage al final del evento.

```js
//SIMULAMOS LA DB
let infoProceso = [
{proceso : "D1", sequencia: 0},
{proceso : "V1", sequencia: 0},
{proceso : "V2", sequencia: 0},
{proceso : "V3", sequencia: 0},
{proceso : "V4", sequencia: 0},
{proceso : "A1", sequencia: 0},
{proceso : "A2", sequencia: 0},
{proceso : "A3", sequencia: 0},
{proceso : "A4", sequencia: 0}
];
if(localStorage.getItem('infoProceso') == undefined){
localStorage.setItem('infoProceso',JSON.stringify(infoProceso));
}
$('#btnGenerar').on('click',(e)=>{
 let nombreProceso = $('#txtNombreProceso').val(),
    cmbProceso = $( "#cmbProceso option:selected" ).val(),
    codigoProceso = $( "#cmbProceso option:selected" ).data("codigo"),
     codigos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('infoProceso')),
      sequencia = codigos.filter((el)=>{ return el.proceso == codigoProceso })[0].sequencia+1;    
if(sequencia != undefined){
$('#txtResultado').val(`${codigoProceso}.PR${(sequencia < 10 ? '0'+sequencia : sequencia)}${nombreProceso}`);
let info = [];
codigos.forEach((el,i)=>{
if(el.proceso == codigoProceso){
info.push({proceso:codigoProceso, sequencia:sequencia});
}else{
info.push({proceso:el.proceso, sequencia:el.sequencia});
}
localStorage.setItem('infoProceso',JSON.stringify(info))
})
}
})

$('#btnLimpiar').on('click',(e)=>{
$('#txtResultado,#txtNombreProceso').val('');
$('#cmbProceso').trigger('change').val('-1')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="txtNombreProceso">Nombre Proceso: </label>
<input type="text" id="txtNombreProceso">
<br>
<label for="cmbProceso">Proceso: </label>
<select id="cmbProceso" name="cmbProceso" class="form-control">                                            
     <option value="-1" selected="" disabled="">Seleccione...</option>
     <option value="1" data-codigo="D1">D1. GESTIÓN ESTRATÉGICA</option>
     <option value="2" data-codigo="V1">V1. VENTAS</option>
     <option value="3" data-codigo="V2">V2. ABASTECIMIENTO</option>
     <option value="4" data-codigo="V3">V3. PRODUCCIÓN</option>
     <option value="5" data-codigo="V4">V4. LOGISTICA</option>
     <option value="6" data-codigo="A1">A1. GESTIÓN HUMANA</option>
     <option value="9" data-codigo="A2">A2. GESTIÓN FINANCIERA</option>
     <option value="10" data-codigo="A3">A3. GESTIÓN DE SISTEMAS INTEGRADOS</option>
     <option value="11" data-codigo="A4">A4. GESTIÓN DE LA INFRAESTRUCTURA</option>
 </select> 
 <br>
 <label for="txtResultado">Resultado Proceso: </label>
 <input type="text" id="txtResultado">
 <br>
 <input type="button" id="btnGenerar" value="Generar"> 
 <input type="button" id="btnLimpiar" value="Limpiar">
```

Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias... ya la corrí y está de maravilla obviamente estudiaré lo que hiciste para así aprender e implementarla en mí proyecto.  Espero contar con tú ayuda en caso de tener más dudas.

Comment: @DavidMez no hay problema exitos

Comment: Disculpa, no sé si se pueda hacer en este medio, o sí es permitido pero. Tengo varias dudas, no sé si puedas por remoto ayudarme a entender esto un poco más; o debo publicarlas una a una en starckoverflow; o sí conoces de una web donde brinden este tipo de ayuda.  Gracias, y me excuso por si es indebido, inmediatamente lo eliminaré. Espero tú consejo.

Comment: @DavidMez sobre que necesitas ayuda ? si es un problema diferente debes publicar una nueva pregunta

Comment: gracias, es todo sobre lo mismo. Esto es una pequeña parte. Soy estudiante y me pasaron un proyecto web para continuarlo.Y tan solo me dieron conexión mediante un s. remoto en netbeana, y es muy básico.. ni siquiera una DB de prueba. Y mi jefe anda muy ocupado y en otra ciudad, así que si tengo dudas toca investigar, pero es muy difícil no tener con quién resolver dudas.  El Proyecto en general es un CRUD, y a estos procesos con los que iniciamos hay que alimentarlos con archivos .pdf, .xlsx, .docx los cuales deben subirse y quedar bajo la misma línea del código autoincremental. .

Comment: @DavidMez necesitas tener por lo menos la estructura y relaciones de la DB para saber si por ejemplo para la secuencia se necesita consultar a la DB entre otras cosas, también se debe tomar en cuenta que backend estas utilizando etc